# Parsing nested tags through XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0

I have a XML file like this -

```
<item>
    <item>
        <tag>value</tag>
        <tag2>value</tag2>
    </item>
</item>
```

I'd like to extract out the inner  tag so it looks like this -

```
<item>
    <tag>value</tag>
    <tag2>value</tag2>
</item>
```

Is this possible through XSLT?

The outer `<item>` and `</item>` are guaranteed to be the first and last lines of the XML document if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to extract just leaf elements (those that have no child elements of their own) then something as simple as

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="descendant::*[not(*)]" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="//item[not(item)]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

extracts those `item` elements that do not contain other `item` elements.